# Ionic2 and get Json

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I am trying to use Ionic2 and I made a service to fetch a local stored Json.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Page1Service {   

public constructor(private _http: Http) {}

public GetItems() {
    return this._http.get('/app/Ressources/Items.json').map((response:   Response) => response.json().data); 

}

public PrintJson():boolean {
   var myresult;
   this.GetItems().subscribe((result) => {
   myresult = result;
   console.log(result);    
});

}
```

I also a made PrintJson() method that just print the json for test purpose.I got the error:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/app/Ressources/slides.json 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't get why. And I can't find an easy and uptodate tutorial. Or should I use fetch()?

Comment: Can you reach the URL outside the Ionic2 application with a 200 status code?

Comment: In an angular2 App... I copy paste the code and change what I needed. (I discovered your blog! tks for your articles). The path is right.

Comment: have you tried `'app/Ressources/Items.json'` as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First copy your json to the following dir(you can create the folder "data"):

```
[appname]/www/data/data.json
```

Type in the following command in your console:

```
ionic g provider JsonData
```

It should create a provider for you.Go to that page and enter the following in `load()` function:

```
  load() {
      if (this.data) {
          // already loaded data
          return Promise.resolve(this.data);
      }

      // don't have the data yet
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          // We're using Angular Http provider to request the data,
          // then on the response it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
          // Next we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
          this.http.get('data/data.json').subscribe(res => {
              // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
              // and save the data for later reference
              this.data = res.json();
              resolve(this.data);
              console.log(this.data);
          });
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually create an Observable wrapped around the api-call like this:

```
public GetItems() {
 return Observable.create(observer => {
    this._http.get('/app/Ressources/Items.json').map(res =>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
        observer.next(data)
        observer.complete();
    });
 });
}
```

Then I have to subscribe on that method in order to get the results and do something with it. (You could be to delegate the result to a list in the GUI)

```
GetItems().subscribe(data=>{
    myResult = data;
});
```

***EDIT:*** It might help to put this in the class as well

```
export class MyClass{
    static get parameters(){
        return [[Http]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And then myResult is the full json? I ll try it tonight.

Comment: Yes it is. Please tell if it works or not after you try it tonight

Comment: Hum. Same error. Do I have to import anything? http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=304121ScreenShot20160427at221358.png

Comment: I am not sure why you get errors. You could try to replace the Observable import on line 3 in your example with this one instead: ``import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";``

Comment: You could also try to put this right below your export class Page1Service: ``static get parameters(){
        return [[Http]];
    }``

Answer (score 0):

Just try to get the response.json() rather than response.json().data in GetItems() method

Comment: Thks. It is just the structure of my json.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of different paths of json files in local browser(computer) and device (android). Create `data` folder inside the `src\assets` folder. Move your json file into that.

When we run `ionic serve`, it will move that folder (with file) into `www\assets` folder. Then do following things:

1. Import `Platform` service of `ionic2`

   ```
    import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
   ```

2. Inject `Platform` Service.

   ```
     constructor(private http: Http, private platform: Platform ) { }
   ```

3. Use `Platform` Service.

   ```
   public getItems() {

       var url = 'assets/data/Items.json'; 

       if (this.platform.is('cordova') && this.platform.is('android')) {
           url = "/android_asset/www/" + url;
       }

       return this.http.get(url)
           .map((res) => {
               return res.json()
           });
   }
   ```