# Angular 2 ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to iterate through nested json array which looks like that

```
{
 "id": 10,
 "nome": "teste",
 "user_id": 14,
 "created_at": "2016-10-19 23:32:49",
 "updated_at": "2016-10-19 23:32:49",
 "exercicios": [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "nome": "teste",
      "descricao": "exericicio de peito",
      "categoria_id": 1,
   }   
 }
```

how i can get the exercicios from this json? 
in my ionic app return only id, nome, user_id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874569/ionic2-and-get-json

Comment: http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api/